# Conditional statements: hypotheses or conclusion?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How to check which part is the hypotheses and which part is conclusion in any conditional statement? If any statement have some keywords like "if...,then...." "only if", "whenever", "unless", "is sufficient", "is necessary" etc present in any statement then I am able to determine which part is the hypotheses and which one is conclusion. But in a sentence like this:

*You only eat what tastes good*

$E(x)$ = you eat $x$

$T(x)$ = $x$ tastes good

domain of x consists all foods

I understand this sentence can be expressed in a conditional form like this (correct me if I wrong)

$\forall x (E(x) \rightarrow T(x))$

or,

$\forall x (T(x) \rightarrow E(x))$

But I my problem is , which one is correct? How can I determine which one is the hypotheses and which one is the conclusion of a conditional proposition like this where no keyword like "if then" etc are not used?

Comment: "P only if Q" always means $P\to Q$. So "You eat only if it tastes good" is the first, not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences you wrote mean, in order,

- All the food you eat is good
- You eat all the good food

Your first one, $\forall x(E(x)\to T(x))$, says that for any piece of food ever, if you eat it, that means it tastes good. Which is what you're after.

The second one, $\forall x(T(x)\to E(x))$, says that for any piece of food ever, if it tastes good, you eat it. Which 1) means that you're going to be very full, very fast, and 2) doesn't say anything about what you do with non-tasty food. You might eat it, you might not, we don't know. So that's not the one you're after.

When you have the sentence $E(x)\to T(x)$, it means, in plain English, "If $E(x)$, then $T(x)$". Which has the same meaning as "$E(x)$ only if $T(x)$". In other words, there is no way $E(x)$ is true but not $T(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Would you please tell me what things should I keep in mind when I want to express a conditional statement in $p \rightarrow q$ form?

Comment: @rtawhidur Experience and practice. If what I said here makes sense to you, then that's all it takes.

Comment: Thanks Arthur for your advice